# Rollup in Vite: Chunks Importing from Main Bundle Causing Duplicate Downloads

Tags: bundle, vite, rollup

I'm encountering an issue with the build process in Vite using Rollup, where the generated chunks attempt to import modules from the main `app.bundle.js` file. This results in duplicate downloads when the main bundle is loaded with a query string in the `index.html` script tag, and later, a chunk attempts to import the same module without the query string.

**Problem Overview:**

1. The `app.bundle.js` file is initially loaded in the `index.html` script tag with a query string (e.g., `app.bundle.js?123`).
2. Chunks generated during the build process attempt to import modules from `app.bundle.js` without the query string.
3. This leads to duplicate downloads of the same module, causing many issues like re-rendering of the app and not loading dynamic pages correctly.

**Rollup Configuration:**
Below is a simplified version of my `vite.config.js`:

```js
 rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'js/app.bundle.js',
        chunkFileNames: 'js/chunk.[name].[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[ext]/[name].[hash][extname]',
    
      },

* it is neccessary to not use app.[hash].js because there is another process that tries to address the app.bundle.js and is not aware of the actual dynamic file name.

addes dynamic import of using react-router lazy method lazy: () => import("./pathtocomponent").
ran vite build.
the result app.bundle.js file which includes a component "Layout" that is used by the dynamic route component.
the created chunk file of the dynamic route tries to import the Layout component from the main bundle.
//chunk.index.3d260d06
import { La as Layout } from "./app.bundle.js";
```